# C# ASP MVC5 Datatable Individual Search column how to filter && and ||

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

**Trying to achieve**

I have managed to pass the values of all the individual columns to `server` using `AjaxGet`. In the following, `pic` or example would be `t` and `v`. 
At the server, I will pass the value to a `filter` method. Now, I am trying to figure out how to properly filter `t` and `v`.
Currently, after `v` is inputted, I will filter `v` and then if `t` is inputted, ideally it should filter `t` for `LOGIN_ID` column and `v` for `NAME` column. However, I am getting `v` or `t` results. Please help.

[image]

**CODE**

```
private List<DataItem> FilterData(ref int recordFiltered, int start, int length, string search, string searchLOGIN_ID, string searchNAME, string searchDT_EDIT, int sortColumn, string sortDirection)

    {
        List<DataItem> _data = CreateData();

        List<DataItem> list = new List<DataItem>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLOGIN_ID))
        {
            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.LOGIN_ID.ToUpper().Contains(searchLOGIN_ID.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNAME))
        {
            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(searchNAME.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDT_EDIT))
        {
            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.DT_EDIT.ToUpper().Contains(searchDT_EDIT.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLOGIN_ID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNAME) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDT_EDIT))
        {
            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.LOGIN_ID.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper()) ||
                    dataItem.NAME.ToString().Contains(search.ToUpper()) ||
                    dataItem.DT_EDIT.ToString().Contains(search.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLOGIN_ID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNAME))
        {
            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.LOGIN_ID.ToUpper().Contains(searchLOGIN_ID.ToUpper()) ||
                    dataItem.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(searchNAME.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLOGIN_ID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDT_EDIT))
        {
            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.LOGIN_ID.ToUpper().Contains(searchLOGIN_ID.ToUpper()) ||
                    dataItem.DT_EDIT.ToUpper().Contains(searchDT_EDIT.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNAME) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDT_EDIT))
        {

            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(searchNAME.ToUpper()) ||
                    dataItem.DT_EDIT.ToUpper().Contains(searchDT_EDIT.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            foreach (DataItem dataItem in _data)
            {
                if (
                    dataItem.LOGIN_ID.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper()) ||
                    dataItem.NAME.ToString().Contains(search.ToUpper()) ||
                    dataItem.DT_EDIT.ToString().Contains(search.ToUpper())
                    )
                {
                    list.Add(dataItem);
                }
            }
        }

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLOGIN_ID) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNAME) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDT_EDIT))
        {
            list = _data;
        }

        // simulate sort
        //=== sortColumn need to change additional column
        if (sortColumn == 1)
        {   // sort LOGIN_ID
            list.Sort((x, y) => SortString(x.LOGIN_ID, y.LOGIN_ID, sortDirection));
        }
        else if (sortColumn == 2)
        {   // sort NAME
            list.Sort((x, y) => SortString(x.NAME, y.NAME, sortDirection));
        }
        else if (sortColumn == 3)
        {   // sort DT_CREATE
            list.Sort((x, y) => SortDateTime(x.DT_EDIT, y.DT_EDIT, sortDirection));
        }

        recordFiltered = list.Count;

        // get just one page of data
        list = list.GetRange(start, Math.Min(length, list.Count - start));

        return list;
    }

public ActionResult AjaxGetJsonData(int draw, int start, int length)
    {
        var searchLOGIN_ID = Request.QueryString["columns[1][search][value]"];
        var searchNAME = Request.QueryString["columns[2][search][value]"];
        var searchDT_EDIT = Request.QueryString["columns[3][search][value]"];
        string search = Request.QueryString["search[value]"];

        int sortColumn = -1;
        string sortDirection = "asc";
        if (length == -1)
        {
            length = TOTAL_ROWS;
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["order[0][column]"] != null)
        {
            sortColumn = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["order[0][column]"]);
        }
        if (Request.QueryString["order[0][dir]"] != null)
        {
            sortDirection = Request.QueryString["order[0][dir]"];
        }

        DataTableData dataTableData = new DataTableData();
        dataTableData.draw = draw;
        dataTableData.recordsTotal = TOTAL_ROWS;
        int recordsFiltered = 0;
        dataTableData.data = FilterData(ref recordsFiltered, start, length, search, searchLOGIN_ID, searchNAME, searchDT_EDIT, sortColumn, sortDirection);
        dataTableData.recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered;

        return Json(dataTableData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**GITHUB**

https://github.com/BROMVC5/BROSTANDARD

Comment: which fields on your controller action do `t` and `v` correspond to? `string searchLOGIN_ID` and `string searchNAME`?

Comment: you'll simplify/eliminate your problem if you go about this the opposite way. Instead of starting with an empty list and finding items that match the filters and adding them to a result list, start with a full list and remove items that don't match the filters. Note if you're working with large datasets that are being queried from the db then both those strategies are very inefficient and you should be filtering as you query items out of the db

Comment: last note, instead of iterating through `_data` each time, just use `.AddRange` and `.RemoveAll`. It'll lessen your code footprint and increase readability substantially

Answer (score 0):

private List FilterData(ref int recordFiltered, int start, int length, string search, string searchLOGIN_ID, string searchNAME, string searchDT_EDIT, int sortColumn, string sortDirection)

```
        {
            List<DataItem> _data = CreateData();        

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLOGIN_ID))
            {
                _data = _data.Where(x => x.LOGIN_ID.ToUpper().Contains(searchLOGIN_ID.ToUpper()).ToList();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNAME))
            {
              _data = _data.Where(x => x.NAME.ToUpper().Contains(searchNAME.ToUpper()).ToList();            
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDT_EDIT))
            {
             _data = _data.Where(x => x.DT_EDIT.ToUpper().Contains(searchDT_EDIT.ToUpper()).ToList();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
             _data = _data.Where(x => x.LOGIN_ID.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper()) ||
                        x.NAME.ToString().Contains(search.ToUpper()) ||
                        x.DT_EDIT.ToString().Contains(search.ToUpper()).ToList();            
            }
             list = _data;

            // past this point this is your original code :)
            // simulate sort
            //=== sortColumn need to change additional column
            if (sortColumn == 1)
            {   // sort LOGIN_ID
                list.Sort((x, y) => SortString(x.LOGIN_ID, y.LOGIN_ID, sortDirection));
            }
            else if (sortColumn == 2)
            {   // sort NAME
                list.Sort((x, y) => SortString(x.NAME, y.NAME, sortDirection));
            }
            else if (sortColumn == 3)
            {   // sort DT_CREATE
                list.Sort((x, y) => SortDateTime(x.DT_EDIT, y.DT_EDIT, sortDirection));
            }

            recordFiltered = list.Count;

            // get just one page of data
            list = list.GetRange(start, Math.Min(length, list.Count - start));

            return list;
        }
```

Edit : OK can't format it. sorry Hanz ...